# How can I put a vertical gap between 2 CSS grids

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
//grid 1 details
const JSONOfReactUrls =
  '{"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
    "https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
    "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials":"Digital Ocean Tutorials",\
    "https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/common-beginner-mistakes/":"React Beginner mistakes"\
    }';

let obj = JSON.parse(JSONOfReactUrls);

for (let key in obj) {
  elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('id', obj[key]);
  elem.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_grid_react').append(elem);
}

//grid 2 details
const JSONOfPythonUrls =
  '{"https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict":"Python dictionary",\
"https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common":"Python Sequence",\
"https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons":"Python expressions",\
"https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit":"Python visualiser",\
"https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480":"Unpacking operator"\
    }';

obj = JSON.parse(JSONOfPythonUrls);

for (let key in obj) {
  elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('id', obj[key]);
  elem.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_grid_python').append(elem);
}
```

```css
.my_grid_react {
  display: grid;
  float: left;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
}

.my_grid_react div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.my_grid_python {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
}

.my_grid_python div {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_grid_react"></div>
<div class="my_grid_python"></div>
```

I created 2 `grids` and used `float` to position the 2 grids adjacent to each other;Now I wish to have a small vertical whitish gap of say 5px between the grid (whose background color is `lightgreen`) and the grid (whose background color is `orange`), please suggest how I can place a vertical gap between the adjacent grids.

Comment: (offtopic) Don't repeat yourself. Makes no sense to repeat a chunk of code that does almost the same besides the target element selector. Create a function instead, pass the selector as function argument. And the JSON as well.

Comment: Typically one uses `margin` to create space between elements in CSS. Have you tried that?

Comment: @HereticMonkey between 2 different adjacent grids, I dont know how to put a margin

Comment: I would start with the [documentation for margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Comment: I put a `margin:10px;` after the `float:left;` but the grid positions are no longer adjacent to each other

Comment: You may need to decrease their widths to make everything fit.

Comment: Just use `display: flex` (or eventually `grid`) and the `gap` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS flex (or grid if needed, [actually a mix of the two](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/z1e3tsLk/))

- Create a parent flex `.row` with `gap`
- Use `.col` flex with `gap`
- Don't repeat yourself in JavaScript, create a function like `createMenu()` that accepts the selector target and the JSON
- Don't name something `Array` which is *clearly not* an Array. (It's a JSON string)
- Don't name something `grid` which is not a grid

```js
// DOM helper functions
const el = (sel, par) => (document || par).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Create vertical menu 
const createMenu = (targetSelector, json) => {

  const elTarget = el(targetSelector);
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);
  
  for (let key in obj) {
  
    const elem = elNew("div", {
      // id: obj[key], // No, please just don't
      innerHTML: `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`
    });
    
    elTarget.append(elem);
    
  }
};

// Init:

const reactURLs = '{\
  "https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
  "https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
  "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials":"Digital Ocean Tutorials",\
  "https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/common-beginner-mistakes/":"React Beginner mistakes"\
}';
const pythonURLs = '{\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict":"Python dictionary",\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common":"Python Sequence",\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons":"Python expressions",\
  "https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit":"Python visualiser",\
  "https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480":"Unpacking operator"\
}';

createMenu(".menu_react", reactURLs);
createMenu(".menu_python", pythonURLs);
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Unneeded, row is by default */
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

/* Customization: */

.my_grid {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.my_grid > div {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.menu_react       { background-color: lightgreen; }
.menu_react > div { background-color: yellow; }
.menu_python       { background-color: orange; }
.menu_python > div { background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col my_grid menu_react"></div>
  <div class="col my_grid menu_python"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: got it but why cant we use a grid approach instead of a flex approach?

Comment: @samreray you can eventually use CSS `grid` but again, with a parent element. I can show you how in a minute

Comment: @samreray see? https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/z1e3tsLk/ try to use `display: grid` instead of `display: flex` for the `.col` and see what happens. So yes, you can use CSS grid where needed but there's also `flex` you can mix them, do whatever you want. It all depends on the end result. Anyways, `gap` is useful in both cases.

Comment: @roko-c-buljan ok as you suggested it works with `display:grid` too and some minor css changes, https://jsfiddle.net/samreray/Lqc7304n/17  . Also you suggested not to use ` id: obj[key] ` any particular reason or is it just to avoid any duplicate div ids ?

Comment: @samreray not only because of possible ID duplication. `obj[key]` holds a string value like `"React Start"` - that's not a valid ID by any means. And you don't need ID at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are floated next to each other, I'll do it the bootstrap 3 way, i.e: adding side-padding for each column, negated with the left most and right most side margin of the row.

1. Just don't forget to `clear` the float afterwards.
2. Of course, you can combine this with media query so for example on small screen, make the width of columns 100% instead of 50%.

```js
// DOM helper functions
const el = (sel, par) => (document || par).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Create vertical menu 
const createMenu = (targetSelector, json) => {

  const elTarget = el(targetSelector);
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);

  for (let key in obj) {

    const elem = elNew("div", {
      // id: obj[key], // No, please just don't
      innerHTML: `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`
    });

    elTarget.append(elem);

  }
};

// Init:

const reactURLs = '{\
  "https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
  "https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
  "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials":"Digital Ocean Tutorials",\
  "https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/common-beginner-mistakes/":"React Beginner mistakes"\
}';
const pythonURLs = '{\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict":"Python dictionary",\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common":"Python Sequence",\
  "https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons":"Python expressions",\
  "https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit":"Python visualiser",\
  "https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480":"Unpacking operator"\
}';

createMenu(".menu_react", reactURLs);
createMenu(".menu_python", pythonURLs);
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.half-col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* add this for responsiveness */


/*
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .half-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
*/

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* removed this: */
  /* width: 100%; */
  gap: 0.5rem;
}


/* Customization: */

.my_grid {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.my_grid>div {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.menu_react {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.menu_react>div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu_python {
  background-color: orange;
}

.menu_python>div {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="half-col">
      <div class="col my_grid menu_react">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half-col">
      <div class="col my_grid menu_python"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- clears the floats -->
  <div style="clear:both"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you modify answer using CSS grid only..( `display:grid`)